# how to select values from two arrays according to a value condition from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I have 3 arrays:

```
a=np.array([-10,-6,-4,0,14,2,4,12,3,6,8,14,11])
b=np.array([0,5,5,6,8,10,2,2,0,0,0,0,7])
c=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,20,8,12,4,3,6,-4])
```

I want to make a plot of `c` (`y-axis`) values against `a`(`x-axis`) values but for only those values that correspond to `b=0` and also only for `a>0`.  So, I want to find a way to produce new arrays which will give:
`a_new= [3,6,8,14]` and corresponding (matching with the indices) `c_new= [12,4,3,6]`. Then I will just plot `c_new vs a_new`.

This is just a sample data. My actual data set is quite large, so it will be great if we can find a method that's fast. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can just use the conditions to index: `a[(b==0) & (a>0)]` -> `[3  6  8 14]` and `c[(b==0) & (a>0)]` -> `[12  4  3  6]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array with your conditions and use it to select from `a` and `c`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

select = (b == 0) & (a > 0)

plt.plot(a[select], c[select])
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('c');
```

Output

[image: a vs c]

Comment: that's a nice concise way Michael! but  if I wanted 0<b<5...it doesn't seem to work. eg how can i set select=(0<b<0.5) & (a>0)?

Comment: Chaining comparison operators doesn't work well with numpy. You need to write the explicit form `(0 < b) & (b < .5) & (a > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the following:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([-10, -6, -4, 0, 14, 2, 4, 12, 3, 6, 8, 14, 11])
>>> b = np.array([0, 5, 5, 6, 8, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7])
>>> c = np.array([4, 6, 10, 40, 22, 14, 20, 8, 12, 4, 3, 6, -4])
>>> i1 = a > 0
>>> i2 = b == 0
>>> i = i1 & i2
>>> a[i]
array([ 3,  6,  8, 14])
>>> c[i]
array([12,  4,  3,  6])
```